# joomla 3 not loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

Joomla 3 is shipped with jQuery, but it seems to me that joomla 3 is not loading jQuery automatically, that is, some joomla pages don't load jQuery, like this sample page http://nyaii.com/t/. I've read some articles, and to my best understanding, joomla 3 will not load jQuery until some extensions need it, and extensions need to call

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

to load jQuery. But, it seems this line doesn't detect whether jQuery has been loaded or not, therefore, if there are 2 or more extensions that need jQuery on a same page, isn't jQuery going to be loaded twice or more, which is what joomla 3 suppose to avoid? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` is the correct way to load jquery in your page. It doesn't load multiple instances if you call it more than once.

Here is some reference to official documentation:

> The Joomla! CMS includes a number of JavaScript Frameworks. Instead of
>   including your own JavaScript code, you may use these pre-existing
>   JavaScript libraries of functions. Frameworks are loaded using calls
>   to static methods in the JHtml class.

Reference: [Javascript Frameworks](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks)